# Kusto Streaming Ingest: ErrorReason=Not Found

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to ingest data with **client.IngestFromStreamAsync** or **client.IngestFromStream** from my c# application but always get the following error:

MonitoredActivityContext=(ActivityType=KustoManagedStreamingIngestClient.IngestFromStream, Timestamp=2021-02-08T17:57:52.0547851Z, ParentActivityId=570e5455-1c3d-4cb4-82ff-a06761e66a30, TimeSinceStarted=1921,1077 [ms])IngestionSourceId=f182ab29-812a-4b44-9d06-1951c7aa972f
IngestionSource=Stream
Error=Not Found (404-NotFound): . This normally represents a permanent error, and retrying is unlikely to help.
Error details:
DataSource='https://table.southcentralus.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/ingest/bla/table?streamFormat=json&mappingName=JsonMapping',
DatabaseName=,
ClientRequestId='KI.KustoManagedStreamingIngestClient.IngestFromStream.ad8c8892-7495-483d-90bc-8585483445fa;73864817-246c-479c-a2da-138aca01b9a2;f182ab29-812a-4b44-9d06-1951c7aa972f',
ActivityId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,
Timestamp='2021-02-08T17:57:53.9596167Z'.

This is how I define ingestion mapping

```
var kustoIngestionProperties = new KustoIngestionProperties(databaseName: databaseName, tableName: rtable)
{         
   Format = DataSourceFormat.json,                
   IngestionMapping = new IngestionMapping()
   {
      IngestionMappingReference = "JsonMapping",
      IngestionMappingKind = Kusto.Data.Ingestion.IngestionMappingKind.Json                   
   }                    
};
```

Before referencing the mapping I create it like this:

```
.create table ingest_table ingestion json mapping 'JsonMapping' '[{"column":"Timestamp","Properties":{"path":"$.Timestamp"}},{"column":"AskRatioVar","Properties":{"path":"$.AskRatioVar"}},{"column":"score_BidRatioVar","Properties":{"path":"$.score_BidkRatioVar"}},]'
```

Any ideas what could cause the error?
All Streaming examples seems to be outdate here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/tree/master/client/StreamingIngestionSample

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that the names of the database, table and ingestion mapping you're passing actually exist in your cluster.

Specifically - in the activity you referenced, you reference an ingestion mapping named `JsonAnomalyMapping1`, whereas the table only has a mapping named `JsonAnomalyMapping`

Comment: Hi Yoni, thank you. I checked everything and I think they are correct... Is there a way how can I test outside of ADE if a mapping exists? Does the error message Not Found (404-NotFound) refer to the missing mapping or could this be something else?

Comment: you can view existing ingestion mappings using the dedicated `.show` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-ingestion-mapping-command

Comment: Do I have to create a database and the table inside the ingest-cluster? So currently all my tables are under the data cluster: https://iexdatacluster.southcentralus.kusto.windows.net and not https://ingest-iexdatacluster.southcentralus.kusto.windows.net

Comment: generally speaking - entities such as tables & their ingestion mappings are created on the *data engine* service (the one you connect to using the *"Query URI"*). streaming ingestion requests that you send on your own (not through a managed client/service) should be sent to the *same URI*. The *data management* service (the one you connect to using the *"Ingestion URI" - the one that includes "ingest-"*) is used for queued/batch ingestion.